# My question is about material-ui 4, material-ui/pickers compaining of inexistent "mask" property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Upgraded a reactjs project using Material-UI (mui) from v3 to v4 and following the recommended migration guide.
As part of that replaced material-ui-pickers 2.2.1 to  @material-ui/pickers.

DatePicker components now complain of inexistent "mask" property which used to work fine on mui3.

Migration guide nothing mentions about Pickers. So I wonder.
For now I rolled back to using mui 3.9 and material-ui-pickers 2.2.1.

```
import { DatePicker, DateTimePicker } from '@material-ui/pickers';

// later on...

return (
    <DatePicker
      name={name}
      value={value}
      clearable
      autoOk
      onChange={handleChange}
      format="DD/MM/YYYY"
      placeholder="___/___/______"
      mask={masked(value)}         // <=== The mask property
      {...other}
    />
  );
```

Expected behaviour is DatePicker should work as in mui v3 since nothing is mentioned on the migration guide.

Actual is the mask property no longer exists for the component.

Comment: what I'm getting is the messsage `The mask "__/__/____" you passed is not valid for the format used dd MMMM yyyy. Falling down to uncontrolled not-masked inpu`, when using `"@material-ui/pickers": "4.0.0-alpha.7"`,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [And now no more need in mask prop](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/guides/upgrading-to-v3#-and-now-no-more-need-in-mask-prop-) section in the [Upgrading to v3 page](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/guides/upgrading-to-v3) says:

> Mask will be generated and applied automatically from the format
>   passed.

And if you look at the [`DatePicker` API](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/DatePicker) you'll find that there is no `mask` property, so you must use the `format` property instead or you can use [`KeyboardDatePicker`](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/KeyboardDatePicker) which has a `mask` property that can be used to override generate from format.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Fraction
Indeed on the legacy code that used  Material-UI 3.9.2, material-ui-pickers 2.2.1,  it didn't complain having both the **format** and the **mask** properties.
The problem appeared once upgraded to Material-ui 4.0.2  and  @material-ui/pickers 3.1.0

Answer (score 7):

In case of a custom date format , you should update also the mask to match the same date format.

Example:

```
 <MuiDateTimePicker
   inputFormat="DD/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
   mask={"__/__/____ __:__:__"}   
   />
```

Comment: Your answer helped me!

Answer (score 2):

for those who just dont want to use the mask, to remove the warnings (caused a performance issue in my case), just pass an empty string mask="", and use the 'locale' prop in LocalizationProvider to set the lang-standard mask.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import AdapterDateFns from '@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns';
import LocalizationProvider from '@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider';
import DateTimePicker from '@mui/lab/DateTimePicker';
import enLocale from 'date-fns/locale/en-US';

class EventForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.localeMap = {
      en: enLocale,
    };

    this.state = {
      date: new Date(),
    };
  }

  setDateTime = (date) => {
    this.setState({endDate: date})
  }

  render () {
    return(
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns} locale={this.localeMap['en']}>
        <DateTimePicker
          mask=""
          renderInput={(props) => {return (<TextField {...props} />)}}
          label="date-time"
          value={this.state.date}
          onChange={(newValue) => {
            this.setDateTime(newValue);
          }}
        />
      </LocalizationProvider>
    )
}
```

Comment: I got this error due to your solution. Why does this error appear for me? "Uncaught RangeError: locale must contain localize property"

Comment: @sandeep.gosavi sorry! that wasn't clear, i've edited the snippet now, language locals are imported: import enLocale from 'date-fns/locale/en-US';